# Assigning onSelectedIndexChacged Event on select tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

1.I am creating a select tag in code behind page using a label control like:

`Label1.Text += "< select >< option >one< /option>< option > two < /option >< option >three< /option>< /select>";`

The += creates a number of select drop downs
i want to associates onSelectedIndexChanged Events on these Drop Downs and want to set Autopostback="true".
Please Help Me.

Comment: Set `autopostback = true` for that select tag.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how to associates onSelectedIndexChanged and autopostback on each dropDown. I've tried it by adding onSelectedIndexChanged='Something' and runat='server' in the select but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**In your code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList loDDL1 = new DropDownList();
    loDDL1.ID = "ddl1";
    loDDL1.AutoPostBack = true;
    loDDL1.Items.Add(new ListItem("one", "1"));
    loDDL1.Items.Add(new ListItem("two", "2"));
    loDDL1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(loDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    Label1.Controls.Add(loDDL1);

    DropDownList loDDL2 = new DropDownList();
    loDDL2.ID = "ddl2";
    loDDL2.AutoPostBack = true;
    loDDL2.Items.Add(new ListItem("three", "3"));
    loDDL2.Items.Add(new ListItem("four", "4"));
    loDDL2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(loDDL2_SelectedIndexChanged);
    Label1.Controls.Add(loDDL2);
}

void loDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}

void loDDL2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Sir, Some of the html controls are already added in the Label1 using label1.text and at this point as u described i'm trying to associate dropDownList in the way mentioned above but this created dropdownlist is not being shown?

Comment: Create all other controls as I mention above and add all of them using Label1.Controls.Add(loDDL2). You can add all asp.net controls using this logic. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to achive what you are trying to do.

Create a dropdownlist in code behind and populate it there it self.

Add a placeholder for this dropdownlist on your webform.

Add the control using placeholder1.controls.add() function.

And set visibility as false for your label.

Now you have the reference of your dropdownlist just subscribe to its selected index changed event.

Comment: Yeah But is there a way to accomplish this in specified constraints?

Comment: You can use javascript or jQuery to achive that.

Comment: i dont speak javascript

Comment: You can go with the @Dexterity answer.